# I have a question about virtual memory, does it actually include values?

Tags: c

I have this question about virtual memory because I want to have a better idea on copy-on-write mechanism applied to paging.

1. suppose we have `int a = 5` in a code, then based on my understand, this would in the process relates a with some **virtual address**, and then this virtual address would be translated to a **physical address** based on the page table. So my question is: virtual address is just addresses, it doesn't include a value such as 5. also, my understanding above might be wrong.
2. based on that understanding, if I `fork` a new process, this child process would have the same **virtual and physical addresses** initially. The child process's page table would be marked as read-only. Only when the child process try to do a `write` then will the OS allocate a new **physical page** and do a copy. My question: so you just change one entry in the page table. The other parts are still some kind of read-only memory so that you don't have a copy, but points to the same **physical address** as the parent process?
3. I found the following on Wiki: *Copy-on-write can be implemented efficiently using the page table by marking certain pages of memory as read-only and **keeping a count of the number of references to the page**. When data is written to these pages, the kernel intercepts the write attempt and allocates a new physical page, initialized with the copy-on-write data, **although the allocation can be skipped if there is only one reference**. The kernel then updates the page table with the new (writable) page, decrements the number of references, and performs the write. The new allocation ensures that a change in the memory of one process is not visible in another's.* I don't understand: (1). why do I need to keep a count of the number of references to the page? I cannot think off my head the benefits of doing so. **It seems like, OK, we know the total don't-need-to-copy processes, but do we need to know what exactly are those processes?** (2). why can the allocation be skipped if there is only one reference? I assume `ref_cnt` global data(actually per process) would be 0 when a parent process was created, then when a child process was created, ref_cnt in the parent process would be 1 now. so when the parent creates another child process, the ref_cnt in the parent would be 2 now, but we can still skip the allocation step(because three page table are the same, we don't need to allocate a new physical page)?

Answer (score 0):

Your understanding of parts 1 and 2 is correct (with some simplifications).  For the questions in part 3:

1. why do I need to keep a count of the number of references to the page?

You wrote it just above: it is so that when the reference count is 1 you know you don't need to copy it because no one else is looking at it.

2. why can the allocation be skipped if there is only one reference? I assume ref_cnt would be 0 in the parent process, 1 in the child process.

Reference counting has to be global, not per-process.

Comment: I actually have a different idea with you, I think ```reference count``` should be per process and even per page in the page table.

Comment: Of course reference counts can be per-page.  But if they are per process they are useless, as you'd not know whether the other process (parent or child) needs a given page anymore, so you'd always have to assume they do, and copy it.

Comment: Can you explain why it cannot be per process more in detail? I am still not getting it.

Comment: If Process A gives birth to Process B, both will have pointers to the same memory pages, with reference count 2.  Then if one of them wants to write, they will see reference count greater than 1 and know to make a copy (and decrement the count for the source).  If the reference count is per-process, the other process won't see this update and will think the copied page is still shared.  That would be broken.

Answer (score 0):

1. yes, **if** the compiler decided to place `a` in memory.
2. yes, but it is *write*, not `write` (if you style it the latter way, people think you mean the `write` system call that reads from memory and writes to a file instead of writing to memory)
3. the reference count means exactly the count of how many places the same *page frame* (physical page) has been mapped to. 1 means it is mapped to one virtual address somewhere, 2 that it has been mapped to 2 virtual addresses and so forth.

   If it is marked "copy-on-write" and the reference count is > 1 then a copy must be made on *write* and then the reference count to the original be decreased. The fresh copy will be mapped in its place in this process and its reference count would be set to 1.

   If the reference count of original page is 1 then there is no need to copy, just mark it read-write because *this* virtual address in this process was the only place that is still mapping that location.

The reference counts **must** be global **and** per *page frame* (physical page) for the scheme to be useful. When you `fork` you will have **2** processes so per-process reference counts to page frames wouldn't be useful.